# Apply uniroot on vector

Tags: r

I would like to find the strike for a given delta using black-scholes. I am able to do this using uniroot for a single spot value and volatility value but would like for this to work across a vector of spot values and vector of volatility values. My below example is simplified, once it works I will expand to much bigger vectors...

I have seen there is a previous post using sapply on uniroot for a different problem. Have tried applying here and not getting much luck.

Would you be able to help me figure out how to do this?

Many thanks!

```
library(rootSolve)
library(ragtop)

CallPut <- 1 # Call
Spot <- c(110, 112, 114)
Rate <- 0 # For simplicity
T <- 0.5 # half a year
Vol <- c(0.07, 0.08, 0.09)
TargetDelta <- 0.5
Lower <- c(100, 102, 104)
Upper <- c(120, 122, 124)

solve.for.strike <- function(Strike) {  
  BS <- blackscholes(CallPut, Spot, Strike, Rate, T, Vol)  
  TargetDelta - BS$Delta
}

test <- uniroot(solve.for.strike, lower = Lower, upper = Upper)
```

Have also tried using uniroot.all but not working:

```
test <- uniroot.all(solve.for.strike, c(100, 120), lower = 100, upper = 120)
```

Have now added libraries.

If any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Function `blackscholes` comes from what package? Not in base R so you should start the script with `library(pkgname)`.

Answer (score 0):

So I have played around and have come up with the following which loops across the vectors. BUT my question is really whether there is a way to apply a solve to the vector to avoid having to loop across each element in the vector?

If there is any more efficient or elegant solution to this than what I have come up with, am very interested.

```
CallPut <- 1 # Call
Spot <- c(110, 112, 114)
Rate <- 0 # For simplicity
T <- 0.5
Vol <- c(0.07, 0.08, 0.09)

solve.for.strike <- function(Strike, S, V, D) {
  BS <- blackscholes(CallPut, S, Strike, 0, T, V)  
  D - BS$Delta
}

loop.uniroot <- function(i, delta) {
  uniroot(solve.for.strike, lower=Spot[i]*0.95, upper=Spot[i]*1.05, S=Spot[i], V=Vol[i], D=delta)$root
}

test3 <- mapply(loop.uniroot, 1:3, delta = 0.5)
test4 <- sapply(1:3, loop.uniroot, delta = 0.5)
```

Comment: Check out the function `vapply` -  it is the most efficient of the `apply` family (something like `vapply(1:3, loop.uniroot, numeric(1), delta = 0.5)`